# Page not found erro with drf-nested-routers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I'm using

```
Django: 2.0  
Djanfo REST Frameword: 3.8.2
drf-nested-routers: 0.90.2
```

My **contacts/views.py**

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Contact.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

class ContactPhoneNumberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.kwargs)
        phone_numbers = ContactPhoneNumber.objects.all()
        return phone_numbers
```

and **app/urls.py**

```
from rest_framework_nested import routers

from contacts.views import ContactViewSet, ContactPhoneNumberViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'contacts', ContactViewSet, 'contacts')
contact_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'contacts', lookup='contact')
contact_router.register(r'phone_number', ContactPhoneNumberViewSet, base_name='contact-phone-numbers')

api_urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(api_urlpatterns)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

using this setup, I'm able to access

```
/api/contacts/           # <= list all contacts
/api/contacts/<pk>/      # <= contact detail
```

But on trying to access

```
/api/contacts/<pk>/phone_number/           # <= list all phone numbers
```

**It is giving `Page Not Found` error.**

I also tried passing `<phone_number_pk>` but still `Page not Found` error is received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
api_urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('', include(contact_router.urls)),
]
```

you also need to register nested urls separately